# How to edit Excel VBA date-calculation code to reflect specific parameters?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a VBA code that applies to an entire worksheet and it updates/calculates various columns based on user input in one specific column (column 46)

shown here:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Columns(46)) Is Nothing Then
If Target.Cells(1).Value = "Performed Audit" Then
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "J").Value = "Performed"
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "K").Value = "Performed"
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AS").Value = "Post-Audit"
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AU").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N"), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AV").Value = "Issue Audit Report"
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AW").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N") + 20, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AZ").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N") + 20, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
   Me.Cells(Target.Row, "BA").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N") + 20, "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
End If
End Sub
```

The problem here is that I need a way to distinguish between 20 calendar days and 20 business days within my code. For example, Column AW is indeed calculated by adding 20 days to the date in Column N, but column AZ is calculated in the same way except it is not just 20 days but 20 business days(monday-friday).

Additionally, any calculated date based on column N cannot land on a weekend (saturday/sunday, it has to be changed to the next monday) or a holiday (shown below)

Labor Day Mon, 2022-09-05,

Thanksgiving Thu, 2022-11-24,

Day after Thanksgiving Fri, 2022-11-25,

Christmas Day (Observed) Fri, 2022-12-23,

Holiday Break Mon, 2022-12-26,

Holiday Break Tue, 2022-12-27,

Holiday Break Wed, 2022-12-28,

Holiday Break Thu, 2022-12-29,

Holiday Break Fri, 2022-12-30

I don't need a full write-up of the code that includes these restrictions, because it would be very lengthy, I would just like some guidance on how to word some of them (then I can do the rest.) My idea was that if it falls on a saturday the code adds +2 days(so it goes to monday), if its a sunday the code adds +1 day, if its a holiday the code adds +1 day until it falls on a business day, etc.

Comment: Excel has workday function. application.workday might help. You can improve it by using a dictionary of holidays.

Comment: Do not do that `Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AU").Value = Format(Me.Cells(Target.Row, "N"), "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` If you use `Format` the date gets converted into text and Excel does not know anymore that this is a date. Never convert a date into text if you can avoid that. Always save the numeric value of the date `Me.Cells(Target.Row, "AU").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")` to format it in your desired format. This way it still is a date and Excel still can calculate with it.